# JLabels placed on top of each other

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, layout-manager

Hello newbie java programmer here, this is probably a really silly question but im having a problem adding multiple JLabels to my view. They seem to be covering each other. i've been reading about the three layout managers but i cant seem to find an easy tutorial on them.

```
    //Size and positioning
    setSize(500,400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Set Frame Background color

    //Set Labels
    JLabel labelTitle = new JLabel("<html><center>My CD/DVD Collection</center></html>",null,JLabel.CENTER);
    labelTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial",0 , 28));
    labelTitle.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    add(labelTitle);
    labelTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 50 /*top*/, 0, 0, 0 ));

    JLabel labelContent = new JLabel("<html><center> created by Daniel Del Core <br> Java</center></html>",null,JLabel.CENTER);

    add(labelContent);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is adding the elements directly to a `JFrame` or `JDialog`, which by default have a `BorderLayout`, so all your labels end up in `BorderLayout.CENTER`. This is why they overlap.

Here is an example of using a `FlowLayout` for your code. Note that I am using a panel to add labels to and the panel is added to the content pane of your window.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//Set Labels
JLabel labelTitle = new JLabel("<html><center>My CD/DVD Collection</center></html>",null,JLabel.CENTER);
labelTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial",0 , 28));
labelTitle.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
panel.add(labelTitle);
labelTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 50 /*top*/, 0, 0, 0 ));

JLabel labelContent = new JLabel("<html><center> created by Daniel Del Core <br> for <br> Java Programming and Applications</center></html>",null,JLabel.CENTER);
panel.add(labelContent);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Comment: Great stuff! I finally understand what the panels are about now :)

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you are calling these methods against a `JFrame`. When you call `add()` on a `JFrame`, you actually add the components to the content pane of the `JFrame` (`JFrame.getContentPane()`). By default, the content pane uses a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border). When you add a component without constraints to a container that uses the `BorderLayout`, you add them to the center. Since only one component at a time can be displayed in the center, you only see one of them.

Try this (just to see the effect):

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

And take a look at these tutorials:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if you want to vertically stack Swing components, use the [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) layout manager. For more information, see [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).